# How to get consistent elevation info with MapBox? queryTerrainElevation() returns different values depending on zoom level

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm running into a problem where I'm finding that queryTerrainElevation() provides different elevation values depending on the zoom level. The difference can vary as much as 50%.

I assume this is because the terrain map is slightly different at different zooms? Presumably because it is more "averaged" the farther you zoom out?

Is there anything I can do to avoid this problem so that users are getting consistent elevation data regardless of what zoom level they happen to be at? I assume it isn't possible by using queryTerrainElevation() as it can only query what is rendered in the viewport. Is there perhaps another(better) way to load this info?

Here is a [quick example](https://jsfiddle.net/1ojg46s0/24/) I tossed together  to show the problem. Simply change the hardcoded zoom and see how the console logged value changes even though it is querying the exact same coordinates.

```
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmNvb3BlcjEwMiIsImEiOiJjbDRpbDllaWkwdDR5M2RvYjZ4eXFoY3RlIn0.UQ7qfSyHKph7Acbuhb1swA';
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        zoom: 15,
        center: [-117.52109099624408, 51.30205367821137],
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v12'
    });

    map.on('style.load', () => {
        map.addSource('mapbox-dem', {
            'type': 'raster-dem',
            'url': 'mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-dem-v1',
            'tileSize': 512,
            'maxzoom': 20
        });
        map.setTerrain({ 'source': 'mapbox-dem', 'exaggeration': 1 });
    });
    
    map.on('idle', (e) => {
        const elev = map.queryTerrainElevation({lng: -117.52109099624408, lat: 51.30205367821137, });
        console.log(elev);
    });
```

| Results |
| --- |
| At zoom level 2 is reports an elevation of 1785.941989487461 |
| At zoom level 2 is reports an elevation of 1785.941989487461 |
| At zoom level 6 it reports an elevation of 1817.0050096897223 |
| At zoom level 10 it reports an elevation of 1314.4484152921011 |
| At zoom level 15 it reports an elevation of 1316.3900277280711 |

This is pretty wild variance. Especially at lower zoom values. According to geological data the elevation of the area around this particular coordinate is between 1300 and 1400 so it seems the accuracy is decent at higher zoom levels but terrible at lower ones.

Any suggestions/ideas would be greatly appreciated as this could potentially be a showstopper for the app we are working on. Is there another way to query elevation information? (any solution would need to be robust enough to query potentially many points. Our use case is our app builds an elevation graph for a route)

Comment: + 1 also seeing this, however requerying after a delay seems to help, even though the initial `queryTerrainElevation` is waiting for map 'idle'

Answer (score 0):

I seem to get more consistent results with the following code. Once the map is idle, then I instruct the FlyTo event, and listen for that to be completed with 'moveend' before querying the elevation.

```
// Once map is ready
  map.once('idle', function() {
                    
    // Position camera
    map.flyTo({ center: wObj, pitch: 70, zoom: 17, padding: -400})
    
    // Get elevation data
    map.once('moveend', () => {
                        
     const elev = Math.floor(map.queryTerrainElevation([lng, lat], { exaggerated: false }));
     $('#converted-elevation').val(elev + ' meters');

    });
  });
```